# Matching btrfs documentation for the version I have?

Tags: btrfs, documentation, system-information

I want to see if the formatting details I specified are doing what I thought, and generally inspect things after a huge amount of copying to the btrfs file system.  Looking through docs, I see `btrfs property`.  But that's not taken by my copy of the program, and `btrfs help --full` does not show such a thing.

The in-program help text is certainly definitive for that version of the specific program, but doesn't explain what other programs are available or give extended examples and advice.  Mint 17.1 is built with btrfs v3.12, which I think may be *behind* the current docs on btrfs site.  So, is there a way to find extensive documentation for a specific version?

More to my immediate case, how can I explore the details of the format: have it repeat back the parameters I used to format it (e.g. raid5 metadata), and give some overview of how data is arranged on the partitions and get stats and such?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a [nice table](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php?title=Getting_started&oldid=26141#Distro_support) on the getting started page of the Btrfs wiki that would guide you what to do with the btrfs tools shipping with your distribution (or what not to do).

I recommend taking a look at the features of newer versions (up to 3.19) on the [ChangeLog](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog) page, and consider downloading and compiling the source of a newer version. The property command was introduced in the 3.14 version.

The online man page for btrfs is [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs), and it includes a link to the [property command man page](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-property):

```
SYNOPSIS

btrfs property <subcommand> <args>
DESCRIPTION

btrfs property is used to get/set/list property, like lable or compression 
state, for given btrfs object.

btrfs property provides an unified and user-friendly method to tune
different btrfs properties instead of using the traditional method like
chattr(1) or lsattr(1).

SUBCOMMAND

get [-t <type>] <object> [<name>]
    Gets a property from a btrfs object.
    If no name is specified, all properties for the given object are
    printed. 
    A filesystem object can be a the filesystem itself, a subvolume, an 
    inode or a device.
    The -t <type> option can be used to explicitly specify what type of
    object you meant. This is only needed when a property could be set for 
    more then one object type.
    Possible types are s[ubvol], f[ilesystem], i[node] and d[evice].
    The <object> can be path of btrfs device, btrfs mount point, or any
    directories/files inside btrfs. 
set [-t <type>] <object> <name> <value>
    Sets a property on a btrfs object.
    See description of get subcommand for a description of objects and 
    object types. 
list [-t <type>] <object>
    Lists available properties with their descriptions for the given object.
    Please see the help of btrfs property get for a description of objects 
    and object types. 

EXIT STATUS

btrfs property returns a zero exist status if it succeeds. Non zero is 
returned in case of failure.
```

---

I am not sure how to find the data for the second question you ask.

```
btrfs filesystem show /your_mount_point
```

might give you some of what you are looking for¹.

---

¹ <sub>I can heartily recommend keeping a ChangeLog of what you do low-level to a system, with at least cut and paste of commands you used. Having that you could just lookup what parameters you used. Keep that log on a different system, or put it under revision control and push it to bitbucket or github. I use commands for partitioning, RAID, LVM, etc not often enough to remember what I did to which system, and that has saved me weeks of redoing research into commands over the last 30 years of handling Unix/Linux machines. I edit that log with emacs ChangeLog mode, which inserts date-time automatically.</sub>

Comment: I read that, as I said in my Question, but my copy of `btrfs` does not admit to a `property` subcommand, and that example gives an error.

Comment: @JDługosz I would just upgrade as I suggested and get bug fixes and new features. 1.4 is more than two years old IIRC and btrfs was not yet stable at that point. Is there a problem with downloading and compiling the source yourself?

Comment: Would it work with the existing kernel? I wonder why a newer version is not in apt if it would work.

Comment: @JDługosz The on disc format hasn't change for a while. For me this works but and I assume even the features you want to use do (I haven't used them). The developers would not bring out incompatible tools without a clear warning. It is not in apt because Mint 17 is based on Ubunut 14.04 and 3.13 did come out in Jan 2014 and did not make it in. Wewer version of software seldom get in after a release, only patches if necessary for security/bug fixes.

Comment: Since you say you are using it, I'll keep that in mind as a possible option, @Anthon.  Otherwise I'd wonder if the userland tool talked to the driver; interpreting the on-disk image directly isn't something I expect a userland tool to do on a mounted filesystem.  Mint 17.2 is coming soon (?), but an Arch or some rolling-release recovery distribution as a separate boot might be best for poking around in file systems anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `btrfs filesystem df <mountpoint>` gives a report like this:

```
Data, single: total=1.45TiB, used=1.45TiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=0.00
System, RAID5: total=16.00MiB, used=176.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=8.00MiB, used=0.00
Metadata, RAID5: total=3.00GiB, used=1.82GiB
```

which shows what I wanted to check on:  that metadata is indeed being stored in a redundant manner and file data is not.